# Higher moments of Lognormal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, lognormal-distribution, moments, method-of-moments

I am experiencing a weird problem modeling lognormal distributions and I am quite stuck on this one.

For a normal distributed variable X following a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution, we have that $Z=e^X$ is log-normal with $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. Additonally, the n-th moment of Z is given as:
$\mathbb{E}[Z^n] = e^{n\mu + \frac 1 2 n^2 \sigma^2}$.

Suppose we are given observations $z_1,\dots,z_m$ from this random variable Z. 
For the n-th moment we have the naive estimator: $\hat{\mathbb{E}}[Z^n] = \frac 1 m \sum_{i=1}^m z_i^n$.

Now, let $\mu=-2$ and $\sigma^2 = 1$. I have done the following. I sampled 10000 values $x_1,\dots,x_{10000}$ from a normal distribution with $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ and computed $z_i = e^{x_i}$. Then, I computed the estimation of $\mathbb{E}[Z^n]$ using the above estimator and compared it to the actual value.

For higher moments, the actual value of the n-th moment seems to explode compared to the estimate, which tends even to 0. The difference is so high, that I am assuming I am doing something completely wrong.

Can anyone help on this one?

Thanks in advance!  :)

Comment: Monte Carlo estimates of higher moments of a lognormal distribution can be problematic, see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427488/

Comment: $\sigma^2=1$ is quite high for a lognormal distribution.  It implies such a great amount of skewness that you shouldn't expect any moment estimator to be stable, perhaps not even the first moment, unless you have a very large sample.